# баг RecicleView

Tags: java, android

При  инициализации RecicleView и загрузки значений в адаптер создается такой вид

[image: при создании]

А когда происходит скроллинг, пункты расширяются.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Первые два пункта расширились и улетели вверх.
как исправить этот баг?
заполняю его так

```
sessia = new ArrayList<>();
if (var.portalSessias[pos].length>0) {

    for (int i = 0; i < var.portalSessias[pos].length; i++) {
       sessia.add(new Person(var.portalSessias[pos][i].discipline, R.drawable.books_32));
    }
}
sessia_card.setAdapter(null);
sessia_adpater = new RVAdapter(sessia);
llm3 = new LinearLayoutManager(getContext());
sessia_card.setLayoutManager(llm3);
sessia_card.setHasFixedSize(true);
sessia_card.setAdapter(sessia_adpater);
```

Comment: Это происходит каждый раз, или как?

Comment: Покажите код адаптера и xml лейаут итема.